# Connecting many LEDs in series on HVDC

Tags: series, hvdc

Is it technically possible to connect, lets say 500 2V LEDs on 1000V DC line? As far as I understand, the voltage would simply be divided in 500 for each identical LED, right? Is it safe to do that? Could I just use plain small diameter low voltage wires for interconnecting (because there's only 2V between LEDs), and only use HVDC cables for both end connections?

I am planning on connecting many devices in series on HVDC, because there are no such devices for higher voltage, so my idea is just to connect them and it should work. (LEDs are just a simple example.)

Comment: yes it is possible. The average LED light bulb has a string of LEDs in series to run off a high voltage - although not 1000V.  You'd have to have some means of limiting the current as LEDs aren't constant voltage. The diameter of the wire determines the current carrying capacity, the insulation determines the safe operating voltage.

Comment: @kart answers go in the answer box

Comment: Away from your question about it being technically possible, how will you deal with reliability? Specifically, if one of the five hundred LEDs fails, how will you identify which one broke so you can replace it?

Comment: _"I am planning on connecting many devices in series on HVDC, [...] LEDs are just a simple example."_ - Erm, so what _actual_ devices do you intend to connect this way? Just because it would work with LEDs doesn't mean it will work with anything. If the devices don't share voltage nicely, things may get explodey. Also, what's the 1kVDC source? What sort of power is behind it?

Comment: **Information:** you can formally accept answers to your previously raised questions and, this just might motivate some folk into leaving an answer (or giving help in comments).

Comment: I will be connecting about 20 peltier Thermoelectric Cooler Modules. The voltage will be 200-500V DC. I just wanted to know is this a safe way to connect them and will I need HV cables only on two sides (not between every module)

Answer (score 1):

While any given LED may have a nominal voltage, this can actually vary by 0.1 or 0.2V, depending on the ambient temperature, the current temperature as they warm up and the batch of LEDs that they came from.

By the time you have strung 500 of them together, that gives quite a bit of uncertainty. The sensible approach is to ensure that the total LED voltage is less than the supply, then add a current limiter. That could be as simple as a resistor.

As for the wires, you need to consider who or what could come into contact with the LEDs or the wires. There may only be 2V across each LED, but it could be as much as 998V between an LED and ground. That sort of voltage can be lethal if touched.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you leave enough distance between positive and negative HVDC input terminals, and between the HVDC terminals and any of the LED's terminals then yes, it's possible.

However...

> LEDs are just a simple example

Now things may change. If the devices have input capacitors then

- There's no guarantee that all of them will share the input voltage equally, and
- at least one of them may expose to high voltage for a very short time because of the empty input capacitors. There's no guarantee that the devices will survive.

Comment: the devices will be peltier Thermoelectric Cooler Modules